# ScrollView cuts out part of upper portion at times

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a problem with a code that I bought from another developer. There is a Scrollview which shows an image and some text...

now the problem is if the text following the image (it's a quote) is too big, then the upper portion of the Image is cut out...

What exactly is this problem and Sorry, I"m unable to define this problem more generically, but I"m sure there is a generic way of rewriting this question to help all...

Thanks

XML below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="360dp"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImg"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/app_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleImg"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/title" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_clicked"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/close" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/topShadow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleBar"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" >
</View>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quote"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="In order to succeed ..."
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
            android:text="- Bill Gates"
            android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottomShadow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" >
</View>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/title_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/star"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/star_on" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
        android:background="#000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the "Center" attribute from within the ImageView

```
       android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottomShadow"
android:layout_below="@+id/topShadow" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/quote"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="In order to succeed ..."
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_below:"@+id/thumbnail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="lucida grande"
        android:text="- Bill Gates"
        android:textColor="#e8d8a7"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, this didn't work, in fact the XML you've provided isn't even complete and has lot of errors